# Batch rename using a .csv

Tags: command-line, batch-rename, csv

I have 700 directories at one location and I need to rename them using a .csv file as shown below:

I want to replace names of Column_A with the entries of Column_B.

```
Column_A           Column_B

 F001               IC500
 F003               IC501
 F006               IC502
 F008               IC503
 ...                ...
```

How do I batch rename the directories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First [export your data as .csv file format](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Importing_and_Exporting_Text_Files) like below:

```
F001,IC500
F003,IC501
F006,IC502
F008,IC503
```

Then run the below script to rename those directories to their new names:

```bsh
while IFS=, read -a dirName; do
    echo mv -v "/singleFolder/${dirName[0]}" "/singleFolder/${dirName[1]}";
done < /path/to/file.csv

mv -v /singleFolder/F001 /singleFolder/IC500
mv -v /singleFolder/F003 /singleFolder/IC501
mv -v /singleFolder/F006 /singleFolder/IC502
mv -v /singleFolder/F008 /singleFolder/IC503
```

- `read -a` used for splitting each line read into array based from `IFS` which I redefined that to comma`,`.
- Each line reads into `dirName` variable.
- With `${dirName[0]}` we are getting the first part of the line(column A).
- With `${dirName[1]}` we are getting the last part of the line(column B).
- `mv` command used for rename there.
  So with `mv -v "/singleFolder/${dirName[0]}" "/singleFolder/${dirName[1]}"`, we are renaming the name of directories from columnA to new-name in columnB which are located in `singleFolder` directory.
- `-v` option shows what is being done during running the command.

---

Also you can use the command without making the content of line as an array like this:

```bsh
while IFS=, read -r oldName newName;do
    echo mv -v "/singleFolder/${oldName}" "/singleFolder/${newName}";
done < /path/to/file.csv
```

Note: remove `echo` command to performing rename on your real directories.

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by name_dir. Is it part of the code? Or is it a directory name that I have to specify? or something else.

Comment: @ChintanSheth no, it just a variable name. you need to change only `/path/to/file.csv` to your .csv file location where you have saved it. and the switch to which directory that all 700 folders stored there and run the code.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command to do this job of course **after** [exporing your data as .csv file format](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Importing_and_Exporting_Text_Files) *mentioned [in previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/561055/283843).*

So after you export it to a .csv file format, use this command to rename easily:

```bsh
awk -F, '{ system("echo mv -v " "/singleFolder/"$1 " /singleFolder/"$2) }' /path/to/file.csv
```

The content of `$1` will be the first ColumnA from .csv file and `$2` will be second ColumnB based on awk's **F**ield separator, is comma `,` which is defined by `-F,` option.

As the same as another answer note it that remove `echo` command to performing rename on your real directories.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can export that data which are stored in libreoffice as a .csv file with **tab** or **space** delimiter and use `xargs` and `mv` like:

```
/path/to/singleFolder$ xargs -a /path/to/file.csv -n 2 echo mv -v
```

**Notes:**

1. You need to switch to `singleFolder` directory first (see the command prompt in command)
2. This method will be failed(unexpected rename) if your directories has an space in their names.
3. Remove `echo` to have actual rename :)